Как посчитать размер чёрных полос полноэкранного режима


var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d')
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx')
var openFullscreen = function() {
  if (canvas.requestFullscreen) {
    canvas.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (canvas.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    canvas.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
document.onmousedown = function() {
  openFullscreen()
}
setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000)
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10000, 10000)
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
  ctx.font = '30px Arial'
  ctx.fillText(canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x, 0, 30)
}, 1000 / 25)
body {
  margin: 0;
}
<canvas id="ctx" width="100px" height="100px" style="display: block;margin:auto;"></canvas>



при переходе через canvas.requestFullscreen() в полноэкранный режим появляются полосы по бокам экрана, размер которых нужно посчитать. canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x не помогает, так как подсчитывает расстояние самого элемента от границы окна. screen.availWidth, screen.width и window.innerWidth не меняют значений при переходе в полноэкранный режим. В примере, на синем квадрате отображается canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x , при нажатии на квадрат значение становится равно нулю, так как канвас занимает весь экран, однако чёрные полосы обрисовываются поверх канваса, так как на них ничего нельзя отобразить. Подскажите, как узнать размер этих полос? Их значение мне нужно знать для правильного позиционирования курсора на канвасе.

канвас растягивается в соответствии с его aspect-ratio, в данном случае 1 к 1. Таким образом высота канваса - это высота экрана, ширина такая же как и высота экрана - все что между шириной экрана и высотой идет на черные полосы по сторонам

непонятно какая проблема с позиционированием курсора появляется, возможно стоит решать именно ее, а не вычислять размер полос

Grundy, при отрисовки курсора на холсте его положение на холсте отличается от реального положения мыши, для этого я использую canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), при растягивании канваса, там более запутанная формула, но как посчитать эти полосы я не знаю. Я бы и не добавлял этот режим, но в мобильной версии моей игры, в горизонтальном режиме слишком много места занимает ссылочная строка сверху. По этому я решил убрать её, открыв полноэкранным режимом.

Возможно, как ты и сказал, стоит вычислять размер ширины, по его aspect-ratio.

Выше в комментарии расписано как посчитать. Добавь пример как ты рисуешь курсор - возможно проще именно ее поправить

Как предложил Grundy, можно пересчитать перемножить разрешение игры, на разрешение экрана, и по максимальному соотношению высоты, получить ширину игры в полноэкранном режиме, а разницей, между новой ширеной и ширеной экрана, будут две полосы
var scallingsiz = (window.innerHeight/gameheight*gamewidth-window.innerWidth)/2
<html>
<style>
body{
margin:0;
}
</style>
<canvas id="ctx" width="100px" height="100px" style="display: block;margin:auto;"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d')
var canvas = document.getElementById('ctx')
var openFullscreen=function() {
  if (canvas.requestFullscreen) {
    canvas.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (canvas.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    canvas.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
document.onmousedown=function(){
openFullscreen()
}
var gamewidth=100
var gameheight=100
var scallingsiz = (window.innerHeight/gameheight*gamewidth-window.innerWidth)/2
setInterval(function(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0,10000,10000)
ctx.fillStyle='blue'
ctx.fillRect(0,0,10000,10000)
ctx.fillStyle='black'
ctx.font = '30px Arial'
ctx.fillText(-scallingsiz,0,30)
},1000/25)

</script>
</html>

